# Parse.com BETWEEN Query

Tags: ios, sql, swift, parse-platform

I don't know if Between is the best to use, but even if it is, I don't know how to use it.

I want something like this:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Class")
    query.whereKey("Number1", between: myNumber+2000)
```

It is incomplete. I want to check numbers on Number1 column and... If myNumber= 3450, I want to retrieve rows where Number1 is between 1450 and 5450

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Class")
query.whereKey("Number1", greaterThanOrEqualTo: myNumber-2000)
query.whereKey("Number1", lessThanOrEqualTo: myNumber+2000)
```